# trouble understanding regular expressions, python

Tags: python, regex

I am quite new to the re module in python, but have been trying to write a regular expression to grab the version number of a file. In most cases this snippet seems to work:

```
test = "filename.ver3_576.exr"
print(re.search("(?!(v|ver|version|vers))\d+", test.lower()).group())
```

but if I change the test string a little, it does not give me the results I would expect:

```
test2 = "filename.ver_3_576.exr" # expects None, because of the underscore, gets 3
test3 = "filenameVe2_version201_1001.exr" # expects 201, gets2, "ve"(exactly) is not something I want to search for
```

I am obviously doing something wrong here, but a struggling to identify what that might be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Comment: Note that `(?!...)` matches if `...` doesn't match next. In your case `ve` does *not* match the `...` and hence the `2` is matched.

Comment: cool... so If is still did want to use a look behind, what expression would you recommend? cheers

Comment: Note that `?!` is **not** a look-behind. `?<=` and `?<!` are look-behind. For example `(?!a)a` does not match `aa` while `(?<!a)a` *does* match `aa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.search('(version|vers|ver|v)(\d+)', test.lower()).group(2)
```

To answer your comment, you didn't use a lookbehind expression. That's a negative lookahead expression. The expression you used is identical to `'\d+'` (not so easy to explain why).

It's not easy to use a positive lookbehind re in this case because it requires a fixed width pattern. The following re, for example, will throw an error: `'(?<=(version|vers|ver|v))\d+'`, so I suggest you use the re that I posted bucause it's the most streight forward.

Comment: Thanks! This works... what was it that I was doing wrong with my expression? I would have thought a look behind would be ok